# Why do I get a 500 (Internal Server Error) when trying to get Modules list in Extensions?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

After developing my website in my local server, I upload it to the web host. When I try to display Modules list in Extensions I get this error (form the web host logs):

> GET
>   http://bamatco.com/dental/prod/admin/index.php?route=extension/extension/module&user_token=XXXXXXXXX
>   500 (Internal Server Error) (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4)

I used the 3.0.2.0 opencart version.

Everything is ok on the local server. I tried to disable all the extensions:

- I uninstalled a pack that was already installed (French language pack);
- I disabled all the Events (in Extensions submenu).

Nothing worked.

Comment: activate displaying PHP errors in your webhosting - or look into the php error log (not in apache log)

Comment: I have only Web or FTP logs that i can see in the logs list.

Comment: Google for "opencart enable error reporting"

Comment: Error reporting is enabled, i didn't get any error for this problem in the log file.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem With Opencart Modules is even if you uninstall the files remains there on the server.

The module list is fetched on the basis of files inside admin > controller > extension > modules
So one way to get rid of this error is remove the new / non default controller files from this folder and the list will populate on the basis of previous files and it will work fine unless the core files code has been modified.

Beside this you should disable modifications and refresh modification so that there is no third party code.

Then you can turn modification and install module one by one and see which one has bug

Comment: I will surely look at error log first but as you mentioned you can't access the log so I have given you this approach to follow

Answer (score 0):

You said that everything works fine on your local server, so if files are the same, database is also the same, the extensions are also the same (same extensions and same list of enabled modules) and you can also load the file that on the remote server returns the 500 internal server error then try one of these options:

1. **Clear the vQmod cache** if you have it installed;
2. **Clear the oCmod cache** (from the ftp go to /system/storage/modification/ and move all the content in a temp foder)
3. **Check your PHP version**, is it the same on the local and on the remote server?
4. **Check which server modules are installed**, compare local and remote configuration with the php function  **phpinfo()** (open your index.php and write it on top of the file:

   phpinfo();

   exit;

.5 **Check your .htaccess**, are they identical on the local and remote servers? If not, try using the htaccess of your local server or disable the htaccess of your remote server and see what happens.